# How to get Tor relay info via python + stem on linux?

Tags: python, linux, tor

I am trying to control tor on ubuntu linux using python's stem library as instructed on tor's [website](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/the_little_relay_that_could.html). However, when I ran the suggested python code

```
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate()  # provide the password here if you set one

    bytes_read = controller.get_info("traffic/read")

    bytes_written = controller.get_info("traffic/written")

    print "My Tor relay has read %s bytes and written %s." % (bytes_read, bytes_written)
```

I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "littleRelay.py", line 5, in module
>
> bytes_read = controller.get_info("traffic/read")
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 852, in get_info
>
> raise exc
>
> stem.InvalidArguments: GETINFO request contained unrecognized keywords: traffic/read

So how can I get Tor relay info via python+stem on linux?
I think Tor is running fine because I started tor from the terminal and it says

> [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
>
> [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done.

Furthermore, when I run the above python code, the terminal says

> [notice] New control connection opened.

P.S. I have also tried the code on a windows pc and it worked. I'm really puzzled now.

Comment: That didn't work but thanks Andre.

Answer (score 3):

That error indicates that Tor doesn't support the 'GETINFO traffic/read' query. This is odd - that is a feature I added to Tor back in 2011. Perhaps your copy of Tor is very, very out of date?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved! Thank you Damian!

I uninstalled Tor on Ubuntu and install Tor again by following the detail guideline [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian#ubuntu). Now Tor works with the python code.

I'm not sure how exactly the problem arose but I suppose the problem had to do with installing Tor on Ubuntu by naively using

> sudo apt-get install tor

Comment: Gotcha. That's actually perfectly fine, but if you have a an old distro then you would get an old instance of Tor. Ubuntu take a snapshot of the Debian repositories when they make a new release so, say, your copy of Ubuntu was released in 2010 then you'd likely have the 2010 copy of Tor.